# Как правильно привязать функцию к кнопку через bind в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток!
Нужно через JS + jQuery прикрепить к кнопке функцию. Написал следующий код:

```js
function writeMessage() {
alert('Вы нажали кнопку!');
}
$('#identificator').bind('click',writeMessage());
```

пробовал так-же

```js
$('#identificator').bind('click',writeMessage());
```

Тем не менее функция исполняется при загрузке страницы, и больше, при нажатии кнопки не выполняется.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: вы ее вызываете, вот она и выполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка в скобках. Вы вызываете функцию на bind:

```js
function writeMessage() {
  alert('Вы нажали кнопку!');
}
$('#identificator').bind('click', writeMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="identificator">Click me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

я не сторонник **jq** вот вам на чистом **javascript** с использованием  *DOM Level 3*

```js
function writeMessage() {
  alert('Вы нажали кнопку!');
}
document.querySelector('#identificator').addEventListener('click', writeMessage);
```

```html
<button id="identificator">click me</button>
```

Comment: так кода больше

Comment: ни этим мерить надо